# Android 4 ICS and Foursquare API

Tags: android, foursquare

Foursquare API for Android (Java) is not working properly on Ice Cream Sandwich, since [HttpURLConnection class has been changed](http://webdiary.com/2011/12/14/ics-get-post/).

The solution is to remove setDoOutput calls from the DefaultIOHandler class, which I did, but I have another problem now. The problem is how to make a (workable) jar file. I made it like that: I converted [foursquare-api-1.0.0.-sources](http://foursquare-api-java.googlecode.com/files/foursquare-api-1.0.0-sources.jar) folder into a zip file and then renamed its extension into jar. Thats how I actually got a jar file, but it isn't working! When I put it into my Android project and build path, Android somehow doesn't "register" it and I cannot import Foursquare classes that I need...

Some advices on how to do that properly would be very helpful. Even more if somebody can provide a fixed Foursquare API.

Comment: you could simply extract all .java files from the jar and put them into your project src folder. No library / jar at all then

Comment: Zapl: want to leave your comment as an answer so Marat can accept it as a solution?